# Does Adsorption Depend On Shape Of The Adsorbent?

Tags: surface-chemistry, isotherm

I was reading about the Freundlich adsorption isotherm and when I read the equation I was quite confused. It states that

$$x/m=k(p)^{1/n}$$

So basically x is mass of the adsorbate adsorbed, m is mass of the adsorbate at pressure p, and k and n are constants, so basically the shape or surface area of the adsorbent do not come into play.

But would it happen like that? I mean, if we take a solid sphere and a cube of same mass and material but different surface area would both have same amount of gas adsorbed?

I have just completed jee adv chem syllabus so if possible please try to keep the answer simple without involving heavy terminologies.

Comment: k and n might depend on the species involved (they are constants for those particular species).

Comment: Please use better formatting if you post again. See the help pages